# how to remove self signed certificates on Mac OS

Tags: macos, maven, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

How to remove self signed certificates from ssl certificate on Mac? I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Some time back,  as per the given project instructions I have added a certificate. Now I did not remember those steps, but because of that maven central is using the certificate from custom trust store instead from certification authority. Because of this I am getting the below error when I run ./mvnw, can any one help me how can I figure out that self signed certificate and remove it so that maven starts using from certification authority instead from custom trust store?

```
$ ./mvnw
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Search the keychain, remove it there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because MacOs related questions should be asked on [https://apple.stackexchange.com/](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The assumption you are making `certificate from custom trust store instead from certification authority` ? Second which Java version do you use?

Comment: It is java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.1